# Calculate total hours, best solution?

Tags: php, datetime

I am making a table with entries, which contains a checkin, checkout and description. Both checkin and checkout are datetime fields.

I want to calculate the total amount of time worked on a project.
This is my calculation between 1 checkout and a checkin:

```
{? $checkin = new DateTime($hour->checkin) ?}
{? $checkout = new DateTime($hour->checkout) ?}
@if($hour->checkout == '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    {? $checkout = new DateTime() ?}
@endif
{? $diff = $checkout->diff($checkin) ?}
{? $hours = $diff->format('%H:%I') ?}
```

Now, I calculate the total amount of seconds by this:

```
$totaltime += strtotime("January 1, 1970 " . $hours . ":00")
```

And then after everything has been displayed, I calculate the amount of *HOURS* by this:

```
public static function format_time($seconds,$separator=':', $format = "%02d%s%02d") // t = seconds, f = separator 
    {
        return sprintf($format, floor($seconds/3600), $separator, ($seconds/60)%60, $separator, $seconds%60);
    }
```

Yet, when I do:-

```
strtotime("January 1, 1970 00:40:00")
```

I get a negative int. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Working with unix timestamps when all you are actually interested in is time differences is a very bad idea. Calculate the individual difference in minutes, sum those minutes up, and format them as hh:mm later. (Again, not using date functions based on the unis timestamp, but simple math.)

Comment: Also, make sure you obtain those times in UTC (or GMT).  For example with the `gmdate()` function.  Otherwise you may get incorrect or weird results around daylight savings time transitions.

Comment: @MattJohnson My timezone is set to Europe/Amsterdam, does that affect it?

Comment: Yes.  [Reference here](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?tz=Europe/Amsterdam).  Example - if you use local time and your `checkin` was `"2013-10-27 00:00:00"` and your `checkout` was `"2013-10-27 04:00:00"` you would think that would be 4 hours, but actually it would be 5.  And if either one of those times was `"2013-10-27 02:30:00"` you wouldn't know what to do because it could refer to either before or after the transition.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$checkin[0] = "2013-03-09 10:00:01";
$checkout[0] = "2013-03-12 10:55:15";

$checkin[1] = "2013-03-15 10:00:01";
$checkout[1] = "2013-03-15 10:55:15";

$checkin[2] = "2013-04-09 10:00:01";
$checkout[2] = "2013-04-15 10:55:15";

$diffSeconds = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($checkin)-1; $i++){
  $diffSeconds += strtotime($checkout[$i]) - strtotime($checkin[$i]);
}
$hours = floor($diffSeconds/3600);
echo $hours.' hours';
?>
```

Comment: It's about the whole worked time, so with more entries. The sum of all hours and minutes.